Chair representation of cyclohexane
I would like to be able to represent the chair conformation of cyclohexane by coloring the parallel bonds (to learn how to draw this conformation). I have a problem because I can't draw the last axial bond (the one linked to the carbon at the top left) or color the last bond of the cycle in magenta.
Does anyone have an idea?

\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{?(-[:190,0.7,,,red])-[:-50,,,,blue](-[:170,0.8,,,magenta])(-[6,0.7,,,teal])-[:10,,,,red](-[:-50,0.7,,,blue])(-[:90,0.5,,,teal])
-[:-10,,,,magenta](-[6,0.7,,,teal])(-[:10,0.7,,,red])-[:130,,,,blue](-[:90,0.7,,,teal])(-[:-10,0.7,,,magenta])-[:190,,,,red]?(-[:135,0.5,,,blue])(-[6,0.5,,,teal])}

\end{document}


\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{?(-[:190,0.7,,,red])-[:-50,,,,blue](-[:170,0.8,,,magenta])(-[6,0.7,,,teal])-[:10,,,,red](-[:-50,0.7,,,blue])(-[:90,0.5,,,teal])-[:-10,,,,magenta](-[6,0.7,,,teal])(-[:10,0.7,,,red])-[:130,,,,blue](-[:90,0.7,,,teal])(-[:-10,0.7,,,magenta])-[:190,,,,red]?[,,magenta](-[:135,0.5,,,blue])(-[6,0.5,,,teal])}
\end{document}



so that the bond is the color you want, do not use a long distance bond (?...?), use a normal bond.
sorry for the answer without examples, I'm writing on a Tablet With no LaTeX

http://www.verbosus.com/android-latex-editor.html :)
